# checking method invocation without using mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I have a system like, it reads data from a source and does some processing and writes its information to database and a file.Is it possible to check method invocation with certain parameters without creating its mock? I know it can be done via Mockito, but it works on mock objects only, not real objects. In this situation, I cannot create mock of all classes used as there are lot classes of different libraries is used internally.

e.g.
 It is happening internally

```
obj.insert(Class1 param1,Class2 param2);
```

I want to check it like this

```
verify(obj,times(12)).insert(any(),any());
```

but obj should be Mock object to check this way, not real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points to consider before testing with real objects.

1. Once we test with the real objects, it is no longer an unit test and it becomes integration test, where you will be testing with real external services like database.
2. This will make your test pass or fail dependent on the status of the external services availability and would take more time than with normal unit test with mock.

> Regarding, possible to check method invocation with certain parameters without creating its mock?

AFAIK, I don't think it is possible.

> I cannot create mock of all classes used as there are lot classes of different libraries is used internally.

Although your classes might be using lot of libraries internally, if we have designed and encapsulated the functionality into individual classes and the class under test is using the individual classes, then all that we have to do is to mock those individual classes and don't need to worry about libraries it is using.

In this case,

> a system like, reads data from a source and does some processing and writes its information to database and a file.

I think you wanted to unit test this functionality. And assuming that we have encapsulated them into individual interfaces, hypothetically, `SourceReader` (reads and processes the data) and `SinkWriter` (writes to db and file). I would mock just these two interfaces and unit test whether the class under test is invoking the necessary methods with proper arguments on these mock objects.

In my view, if the system is not allowing us to mock the objects, I doubt and would consider refactor the code. Because one of the goals of unit testing is to promote better design (especially with Behavior based unit testing) and if we are not able unit test it easily it means the code has become complex and needs some refactoring.

Comment: it is somehow possible to inject a mock object inside an object? I wan to test invocation of particular method of a class, and its object is created in side another class. <br>
class C2{
C1 c1=new C1();
c1.someMethod(someParams);
}
<br>
is it possible to inject a mock of c1 inside c2? so that i can verify invocation of method of c1.

Comment: @xrs Invocation of particular method of a class, say XYZ, can be tested (only) as long as the class (XYZ) is mock.

Comment: is it possible to inject Mock of XYZ into a class ABC? as Object of class ABC is automatically created with injected mock of XYZ. so that we can verify method invoked of XYZ inside object of ABC?

Comment: @xrs Assuming have a way to inject the XYZ class in the ABC either through constructor or setter method, it is possible to inject a mock of XYZ into ABC and check method invoked on mock or not. Can you say more about `automatically created with injected mock of XYZ`?

Comment: it is event dependent, whenever i get new data at source, all process automatically triggers. So, I am trying to inject mock of a particular class in between that process and check that particular method on mock is invoked or not.